# Как в PyQt5 независимо запустить два долгоиграющих скрипта?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qprocess

Есть две кнопки (1 и 2).

При нажатии на кнопку 1 запускается файл **script_1.py**, который выполняет долгую задачу.

Кнопкой 2 запускается **script_2.py**, который также выполняет долгую задачу.

Проблема в том, что пока не выполнится **script_1.py**, кнопка 1 не запускает **script_2.py**. Что нужно дописать, чтобы кнопка 2 не ждала окончания выполнения **script_1.py**?

***main.py***

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
import os


class New(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(New, self).__init__()

        loadUi("form.ui", self)

        self.FB_1.clicked.connect(self.file_1)
        self.FB_2.clicked.connect(self.file_2)

    def file_1(self):
        os.system("script_1.py")

    def file_2(self):
        os.system("script_2.py")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = New()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

***form.ui***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>160</width>
    <height>280</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>160</width>
    <height>280</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>160</width>
    <height>280</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-color: qradialgradient(spread:pad, cx:0.5, cy:0.5, radius:0.5, fx:0.5, fy:0.5, stop:0 rgba(0, 223, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(25, 58, 73, 255));</string>
  </property>
  <property name="sizeGripEnabled">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="modal">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_7">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>5</x>
     <y>5</y>
     <width>150</width>
     <height>270</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="minimumSize">
    <size>
     <width>0</width>
     <height>270</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="maximumSize">
    <size>
     <width>16777215</width>
     <height>270</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">background-color: qradialgradient(spread:pad, cx:0.5, cy:0.5, radius:0.5, fx:0.5, fy:0.5, stop:0 rgba(0, 223, 255, 255), stop:0.9801 rgba(29, 34, 36, 255));</string>
   </property>
   <property name="title">
    <string/>
   </property>
   <widget class="QVideoWidget" name="VIDEO_widget" native="true">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>150</width>
      <height>270</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="sizePolicy">
     <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
      <horstretch>0</horstretch>
      <verstretch>0</verstretch>
     </sizepolicy>
    </property>
    <property name="minimumSize">
     <size>
      <width>150</width>
      <height>270</height>
     </size>
    </property>
    <property name="maximumSize">
     <size>
      <width>150</width>
      <height>270</height>
     </size>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);</string>
    </property>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="FB_1">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>10</x>
       <y>20</y>
       <width>60</width>
       <height>40</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="maximumSize">
      <size>
       <width>100</width>
       <height>50</height>
      </size>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <pointsize>9</pointsize>
       <weight>75</weight>
       <bold>true</bold>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    background-color: qradialgradient(spread:pad, cx:0.5, cy:0.5, radius:0.5, fx:0.5, fy:0.5, stop:0 rgba(107, 134, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(185, 241, 255, 255));   
    border-color: #8F8F91;
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}


QPushButton:default {
    border-color: royalblue; /* make the default button prominent */
}
QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: white;
    border-color: qradialgradient(spread:pad, cx:0.5, cy:0.5, radius:0.5, fx:0.5, fy:0.5, stop:  0.199005 rgba(29, 43, 65, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));
    border-style: inset;
}</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>1</string>
     </property>
     <property name="iconSize">
      <size>
       <width>40</width>
       <height>40</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="FB_2">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>80</x>
       <y>20</y>
       <width>60</width>
       <height>40</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="maximumSize">
      <size>
       <width>100</width>
       <height>50</height>
      </size>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <pointsize>9</pointsize>
       <weight>75</weight>
       <bold>true</bold>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    background-color: qradialgradient(spread:pad, cx:0.5, cy:0.5, radius:0.5, fx:0.5, fy:0.5, stop:0 rgba(107, 134, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(185, 241, 255, 255));   
    border-color: #8F8F91;
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}


QPushButton:default {
    border-color: royalblue; /* make the default button prominent */
}
QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: white;
    border-color: qradialgradient(spread:pad, cx:0.5, cy:0.5, radius:0.5, fx:0.5, fy:0.5, stop:  0.199005 rgba(29, 43, 65, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));
    border-style: inset;
}</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>2</string>
     </property>
     <property name="iconSize">
      <size>
       <width>40</width>
       <height>40</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>QVideoWidget</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс `QProcess` используется для запуска внешних программ и связи с ними.

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html

```
import sys
#import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets                           # +++
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class New(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(New, self).__init__()

        loadUi("form.ui", self)

        self.FB_1.clicked.connect(self.file_1)
        self.FB_2.clicked.connect(self.file_2)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def file_1(self):
#        os.system("script_1.py")
        self.FB_1.setEnabled(False)
        self._process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
#                                      "script_1.py"        
        self._process.start('python', ["q1367803.py"])
        self._process.finished.connect(lambda: self.FB_1.setEnabled(True))        

    def file_2(self):
#        os.system("script_2.py")
        self.FB_2.setEnabled(False)
        self._process2 = QtCore.QProcess(self)
#                                       "script_2.py"   
        self._process2.start('python', ["q1367438.py"]) 
        self._process2.finished.connect(lambda: self.FB_2.setEnabled(True))  
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = New()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]